# How to approach dataframe list to html (how to iterate in html code)?

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

I have serveral pandas dataframes in a list. So I have several dataframes (df[0], df[1]). Each dataframe I want to write to html.

The html code in the python file looks as follows:

```
html = f'''
        <html>
           <head>
                title>{"test"}</title>
           </head>
           <body>
                 <p>{"just a test sentence"}</p>
           <body>
        <html>
'''
```

To write just a normal df it is quite easy (**{df.head(5).to_html()}**):

```
html = f'''
        <html>
           <head>
                title>{"test"}</title>
           </head>
           <body>
                 <p>{"just a test sentence"}</p>
                 {df.head(5).to_html()}
           <body>
        <html>
'''
```

How to approach it in my case where I have df[0], df[1] and so on. How to iterate over df list in html to show each of them among each other?
Of course I just can use **{df[0].head(5).to_html()}**. But I don't know how many dataframes are in the list and therefore i have to use a for loop for example. But I don't know how to insert a for loop into the html code. Thanks

Comment: Show the expected Output , will try to figure it out and data in which format

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to join the HTML strings of all DataFrames into a single one.

Just create a function that produces the HTML code for a given DataFrame

```py
def df_to_html(df):
    return f'''
        <html>
           <head>
                <title>{"test"}</title>
           </head>
           <body>
                 <p>{"just a test sentence"}</p>
                 {df.head(5).to_html()}
           <body>
        <html>'''
```

Then iterate over the list of DataFrames, call the function on each, and finally use `str.join` to concatenate the resulting HTML codes.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a list of 3 random DataFrames with shape (10, 3)
# just for the sake of example
df_list = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,3)), 
                        columns=list("ABC")) 
             for _ in range(3)]

# iterate over the dfs, generate the HTML, and concatenate the results
all_df_html = "".join(df_to_html(df) for df in df_list)

>>> print(all_df_html)
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>just a test sentence</p>
  <table border="1" class="dataframe">
    <thead>
      <tr style="text-align: right;">
        <th></th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>0</th>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <body>
    <html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <title>test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <p>just a test sentence</p>
      <table border="1" class="dataframe">
        <thead>
          <tr style="text-align: right;">
            <th></th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>0</th>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>2</th>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>3</th>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>4</th>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <body>
        <html>
        <html>

        <head>
          <title>test</title>
        </head>

        <body>
          <p>just a test sentence</p>
          <table border="1" class="dataframe">
            <thead>
              <tr style="text-align: right;">
                <th></th>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>0</th>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>7</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>9</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>4</th>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <body>
            <html>
```

Comment: Thanks for input. How is it possible to give another type of output JUST for loop number 1?
So I mean: Not using "just a test sentence" for the first loop but e.g. "this is the first sentence".